# Applying control template modifications

Tags: c#, xaml, templates, controltemplate, attached-properties

I use attached property to alter several properties of a control template like so:

```
public override void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is MenuItem item)
    {
        if (item.Template.LoadContent() is FrameworkElement element)
        {
            if (element.FindName("borderRoot") is Border b)
            {
                b.Margin = new Thickness(5);
                b.BorderThickness = new Thickness(5);
                b.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that changes are not being applied using the above approach. There is simply no change visible.

I have tried applying the template using `ApplyTemplate` method, without any result:
`element.ApplyTemplate();`

**Why is that? How can I properly update the control template properties?**